# erc721 was created but does not appear in wallet

Tags: solidity, javascript, erc-721

I am attempting to create a Factory which mints NFTs and while it seems that my transaction has completed, metamask does not register the NFT. See the screenshots of my app: https://imgur.com/a/XWxgQJb

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

import "./ERC721Token.sol";

contract Factory {
  event ERC721TokenCreated(address tokenAddress);

  function deployNewERC721Token(string memory name, string memory symbol)
    public
    returns (address)
  {
    ERC721Token t = new ERC721Token(name, symbol);
    emit ERC721TokenCreated(address(t));

    return address(t);
  }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract ERC721Token is IERC721Metadata, ERC721URIStorage {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  event awardNewItem(uint256 indexed newItemId);

  constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol)
      ERC721(name, symbol)
  {}

  function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI)
      public
      returns (uint256)
  {
      _tokenIds.increment();

      uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
      _mint(player, newItemId);
      _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

      emit awardNewItem(newItemId);

      return newItemId;
  }
}
```

```
var factory = new web3.eth.Contract(FactoryJson.abi, FactoryAddress);

const deployedERC721Token = await factory.methods
  .deployNewERC721Token("Demo ERC721 Token", "DEMO721")
  .send({
    from: web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
    gasPrice: '1000000000000',
    gas: 5000000
  });
  
console.log("deployedERC721Token", deployedERC721Token);
```

Comment: Does the token appear in a block explorer?

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am wondering what needs to happen for a wallet to see an erc721 as well